While script is running, how to disable a 'Hotkey If, <epression>'?
I have the following script, the x hotkey can only be fired if active has 1, this is as desired:
#singleinstance, force
active := 1

Hotkey If, (active)
#If (active)
x::
tooltip, x is pressed
return
#If

z::
;disable the Hotkey If, (!MG_Active) condition for "x"s
return

Later on during the scripts life time need to remove this Hotkey If, <epression> equation from the script, as the scripts code entirely consists of the following, thus x hotkey always fires regardless of what active has:
#singleinstance, force
active := 1

x::
tooltip, x is pressed
return

z::
;disable the Hotkey If, (!MG_Active) condition for "x"s
return

While writting this, I realised I could just use z to set active to 0, but I really need to figure how this aspect of the hotkey command works. I spent all day stuck on this.

You don't need a boolean variable for disabling/re-enabling a hotkey while the script is running. Change only its second parameter to On, Off or Toggle:
x:: MsgBox, x is pressed

y:: 
    Hotkey, x, off
    Sleep 10000  ; do something
    Hotkey, x, on
return

z:: Hotkey, x, toggle


I am afraid this route is not an option for me. There are hundreds of hotkeys involved. I showed a limited hotkeys in my example purely for brevity.

Hundreds of hotkeys? How can you remember all of them? You can create an array of those hotkeys and use a For-Loop for disabling all or a part of them If (!MG_Active).

Imao that just for one programme (Base, Ctrl, Shift, Alt, Ctrl + Shift etc). I thought it was common to have tons of hotkeys, I remeber them fine. This question is just meant for solving an edge case problem, of which I thought this hotkey command was the key to.

You can also try the Suspend command.
